# Azure Function (JS) using SendGrid with attachment

Tags: javascript, azure, azure-functions, sendgrid

I want to send emails with attachment from an Azure function (Javascript) using SendGrid. I have done the following

1. created a new AppSettings for SendGrid API Key
2. SendGrid output binding set of Azure Function
3. Following is my Azure Function

   ```
   module.exports = function (context, myQueueItem) {
   var message = {
    "personalizations": [ { "to": [ { "email": "testto@test.com" } ] } ],
   from: { email: "testfrom@test.com" },        
   subject: "Azure news",
   content: [{
       type: 'text/plain',
       value: myQueueItem
   }]
   };
   context.done(null, {message});
   };
   ```

Email is getting send correctly. But how do i add an attachment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try following snippet from Sendgrid API:

```
const sgMail = require('@sendgrid/mail');
sgMail.setApiKey(process.env.SENDGRID_API_KEY);
const msg = {
  to: 'recipient@example.org',
  from: 'sender@example.org',
  subject: 'Hello attachment',
  html: '<p>Here’s an attachment for you!</p>',
  attachments: [
    {
      content: 'Some base 64 encoded attachment content',
      filename: 'some-attachment.txt',
      type: 'plain/text',
      disposition: 'attachment',
      contentId: 'mytext'
    },
  ],
};
```

So in your context:

```
module.exports = function (context, myQueueItem) {
var message = {
 "personalizations": [ { "to": [ { "email": "testto@test.com" } ] } ],
from: { email: "testfrom@test.com" },        
subject: "Azure news",
content: [{
    type: 'text/plain',
    value: myQueueItem
}],
attachments: [
    {
      content: 'Some base 64 encoded attachment content',
      filename: 'some-attachment.txt',
      type: 'plain/text',
      disposition: 'attachment',
      contentId: 'mytext'
    },
  ]
};
context.done(null, {message});
};
```